# Most power efficient location tracking implementation? Intent/BroadcastReceiver/LocationListener/Service/IntentService/AlarmManager?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, intentservice, locationlistener

I have been through solutions and found that there are a lot of ways to implement a location tracking logic.

1. Intent+BroadcastReceiver+LocationListener
2. Intent+IntentService+AlarmManager
3. LocationListener
4. other techniques or different combinations of the above...

I am trying to find out what would be the best practice(most power efficient way) to achieve the same...

I have a library class MyLocationClass.java which has two methods 
1. startTracking() - Start sending user location after T time and only if the user has moved X distance
2. stopTracking() - stop sending location updates.

A simple answer seems to be a LocationListener because of its inbuilt Time Passed/Distance Moved features which provides a better user experience, but then...

I don't want the GPS to be on all the time? In fact it should be only switched on when T and X are crossed. Will using a Service/IntentService and/or/with an alarm manager Timer will be a better solution? Can BroadcaastReceivers with LocationListeners prove to be the better solution?

Please suggest.

Comment: It all depends what you want to do with the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you can use the Location Listener implemented in a service. Start listening the GPS when the service starts and remove the GPS listener when the service stops. Start this service when you wants to listen to GPS.

Also please take a look at the "requestLocationUpdates" method. The minTime and minDistance fields of this function is explained as follows:

minTime     the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.

minDistance     the minimum distance interval for notifications, in meters

Answer (score 0):

```
 > Most power efficient location tracking implementation?
```

The most power-efficient (and inacurate) solution is to **not use gps** at all because the gps-receiver (at least on my samsung-smartphone) increases powerconsuption significantly.

if your android app is running on a cell phone that is logged in to its cellphone provider there are **cellphone cellid-broadcasts** that tell the phone that the cell-positon has changed. Your app can receive these. too.

The cellphone-receiver is already running and the cellphone has to wake up to keep connected so there is minimal energy overhead.

however you must find a way to translate the cell-id back to a location.

The android app [llama](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) uses this cellid-broadcast to trigger location based actions. It  has a learning mode where i can say: "Now i am at my job for 7 hours. In the background it collects all cellid-s and mark these as "job".

Comment: thanks k3b. My question is more on which of the implementation would produce best result keeping other parameters(CellTower Triang/GPS constant). So lets say I have to use GPS for accuracy, now how should I implement the logic? Should I choose Listeners or Receivers or Service etc...?

Comment: You got a answer already, Location Listener implemented in a service.